# dweetpro javascript API

Tags: javascript, dweet.io

I am migrating working code from regular dweet.io to dweetpro.io

In the javascript API documentation for dweetpro, it says to initialize using

```
var dweetClient = require("dweetio-client");
var dweetio = new dweetClient("username", "password");
```

But "require" is not supported in client side javascript.
What do I need to do?

Comment: Looks like they want you to use a NodeJS based build system like Webpack

Answer (score 0):

For client-side usage, you'd need to use a 3rd party package in order to require packages the same way you would in node. You can take a look at [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) or [browserify](https://browserify.org/#install).

Another way is to use [this package](https://github.com/buglabs/dweetio-client), not sure if this is the same package that you mentioned in your question, but you can use it client-side.

Update:
According to [dweet.io](http://dweet.io/), [this is the official javascript package](https://github.com/buglabs/dweetio-client) if you want to use it client-side

Comment: The javascript packages pointed out above are for regular dweet and not for dweetpro, I believe.

Comment: The package I am using is
  <script src="https://dweetpro.io/client/dweet.io.min.js"></script>
As per the official API documentation at
https://github.com/buglabs/dweetio-client-v2 (Official)

All very confusing …

Comment: Mamdouh - is the package you mention for dweet or dweetpro? Because I see that the arguments for listen_for are missing the "my-key" argument ...